# Angular 2 Spring Boot Login CORS Problems

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, spring-boot, cors, angular-http

I am trying to develop an application with Spring Boot for the back end and Angular 2 for the front end.

Actually i have connection problems, when i accessing on the mvc login page from spring.

I get following Problems:

( Console )

[image]

( Angular 2 Code )
 [image]

Spring Code [image]

[image]

I have set a global Cors Configuration for the FrontEnd port. My Request returns with the Response status 200. But i cant access the Response because i getting the error message in the Console.

Spring dosnt have errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing you need to understand Cors configuration is added in the backend. You do not need to send cors header with each request from Angular2 App. Understanding that, this problem is easily fixed by adding global CORS configuration in your spring security configuration class.

First you need to create a filter bean :

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCorsFilter implements Filter{

public MyCorsFilter () {
    super();
}

@Override
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");

    // without this header jquery.ajax calls returns 401 even after successful login and SSESSIONID being succesfully stored.
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type");

    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
        // do not continue with filter chain for options requests
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

} 

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {       
}
}
```

STEP 2: In your spring security configuration class add :

```
@Autowired
private MyCorsFilter myCorsFilter;


//CORS
http.addFilterBefore(myCorsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
```

EDIT : 
This configuration assumes you have angular2 app running at localhost:3000

Comment: **Thanks**, this was the first Problem with Cors. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In case, you are working with Spring 4.2 and further releases, there is a firstclass support for CORS out-of-the-box. Read this [page](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

You could get away by defining following annotation at the class level:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", maxAge = 3600)
```