# Can not set certain HTTP header key value pairs correctly in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, spring-boot

I have a issue by adding some HTTP header key value to a http.post. It should be very simple but I am not getting correctly set. We are using on server side a spring-boot and on client side angular framework.
Our backend request the following header values:

```
'Content-Type' = 'application/json' 
'X-Requested-With' = 'XMLHttpRequest' 
'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache'
```

In angular, I create a header, this header I add a RequestOptions and add this options to the post request.
See code below:

```
.....
    let myHead = new Headers();
    myHead.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myHead.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    myHead.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHead });

    return this.http.post(ServerUrl,data, options).map((response: Response) => {..//do Something...}

...
```

The problem is, if I am checking the post request, I see that the header is not correctly set. 
[image]

As you can see above it is not correctly set as a key value as I am expecting!?

If I do this with a tool e.g. postman plugin you see how it should be done corretly:

```
POST /ias-vwa/api/auth/login HTTP/1.1
Host: de00-fm26-l1:9090
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c9bc0404-bc1e-57eb-fca4-07bba9ee6d93
```

I tried a lot of different options to set the header but I was always ending up that it will be always set in one line like this:

**Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin,cache-control,content-type,x-requested-with**

The error I get on the browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://t00:9090/ias-vwa/api/auth/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Can any body give me a hint on that?

Comment: May I ask what backend are you using to complete the API call?

Comment: We are using  **RESTFul-Server of SpringBoot** which is writen in Java. We had the problem with CORS but this we solved by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved this issue. 
As mention in this article and from Yordan Nikolov it's a CORS issue

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests
```

If in some circumstances (as described in the article) the browser will send a Preflight-Request. In this request the custom value will be only named as in Access-Control-Request-Headers. This request will be HTTP request by the OPTIONS method. The server in our case a spring-boot need to implement a filter to filter this request and evaluate this cutsom header to be allowed. After the preflight request has be responed with a HTTP 200 the client will send the actually request with including the custom headers. This CORS issues is important if a request comes from a other domain.

So, the setting of the client side (angular2) will be set correctly.

Hope it helps anybody

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to POST to different domain from yours (your app live), and you're running on CORS issue.
You need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin as a header in your response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: We are using a Java WebService **RestFul-Server of SpringBoot** and we setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * we had this Problem before and solved it. I don't think ist is a CORS problem because if you see the Header Request you see that he is not adding the key-value correctly. I also added the Access-Control-Allwo-Origin: *  on the client side. We can see wenn we debug the Request in the Server that the Key-Value Pair of the header is not correctly set.

Comment: The error come because the key value of X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest is not found, which is expected by the server. If I do this with a tool like postman and the key value X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest is correctly set all is fine.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cant help you more for now. I dont have expirience with SpringBot. You may take a look on those two urls, may be they can help you :
http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864171/angular-2-spring-boot-login-cors-problems

Comment: Thank you very mich  anyway