# Angular2/Spring Boot Allow Cross Origin on PUT

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular

I have a little problem on my web application: an angular2 app connected to a spring boot API.

I can't access my request from the angular2 app. I get this error :

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/deliveryMan/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Java code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/deliveryMan")
@CrossOrigin
public class DeliveryManController {

    @Autowired
    DeliveryManService deliveryManService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDeliveryMan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<DeliveryMan> getAllDeliveryMan(){
        return deliveryManService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
    public DeliveryMan addDeliveryMan(@RequestBody DeliveryMan deliveryMan) throws InvalidObjectException {
        deliveryManService.save(deliveryMan);
        return deliveryMan;
    }

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class MyApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The angular2 code :

```
private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/deliveryMan/';

getAll(): Promise<DeliveryMan[]> {
  const url = this.apiUrl + 'getAllDeliveryMan';
  return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as DeliveryMan[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

saveDeliveryMan(deliveryMan: DeliveryMan): Promise<DeliveryMan> {
  const url = this.apiUrl;
  return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(deliveryMan), this.headers)
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => deliveryMan)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In order to solve the problem, i added @CrossOrigin to my controller class. 
It resolves the problem for the getAll method but not for the additional one.

How to resolve it so I can use PUT methods without getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `CORSFilter.java` file in your project.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * CORS filter for http-request and response
     */
    public CORSFilter() {
    }

    /**
     * Do Filter on every http-request.
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access_token, authorization, content-type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy method
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /**
     * Initialize CORS filter 
     */
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

You can refer this post [Angular 2 Spring Boot Login CORS Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864171/angular-2-spring-boot-login-cors-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` annotation to your controllers like:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
    public DeliveryMan addDeliveryMan(@RequestBody DeliveryMan deliveryMan) throws InvalidObjectException {
        deliveryManService.save(deliveryMan);
        return deliveryMan;
    }
```

Comment: As i said to @Amit : It doesn't change anything... The documentation says : "By default all origins and  GET, HEAD and POST methods are allowed". Even with (origins = "http://localhost:4200") it don't work for my PUT method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just: (It should be work for all CRUD operations)

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything... The documentation says : "By default all origins and  GET, HEAD and POST methods are allowed". Even with (origins = "*") it don't work for my PUT method.