# Failed to get data when accessing the rest-api method getAll

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot

I'm developing an application which has UI from **Angular2** and **back-end** as a rest api which is done on **Spring-boot**.

When I access the URL to get the list of users, it doesn't fetch all the users. When I check the browser console I get the following error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/api/user/getAll: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: is the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is sent from the spring application along with responses. Angular has nothing to do with it.

Comment: it is an issue from the backend. Your backend should allow requests from all origins.

Comment: Here is an example to enable cors on spring, `https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/`

Comment: @CrossOrigin annotation solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 1):

If the frontend (Angular2) and backend (Boot) live on two different domains a solution would be to enable cors on the backend. Read here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html and here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/