# Angular PUT request is Forbidden over SSL

Tags: angular, ssl, spring-boot, cas

I am using Angular 5 as a front end with a Spring Boot REST server.  Everything was working properly if not using SSL.  When I switch to SSL, eventually I got everything sort of working.  It works for GET requests, but so far I cannot get a PUT request to go through.

My guess is that this is some kind of a CORS issue, given that GET is a simple request and PUT is apparently not ([CORS reference](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)), but I cannot figure out how to fix the problem.

On my Spring Boot Rest Controllers, I have the annotation `@CrossOrigin("*")`, so I don't think that is the problem, but I'm not sure.

The other piece of the puzzle is that authentication is handled through a CAS server.  I have added the following configuration to the CAS properties.  These were the final piece that allowed GET requests to work, but I'm not sure what to change on them (if anything) to handle PUT requests:

```
cas.httpWebRequest.cors.enabled=true
cas.httpWebRequest.cors.allowOrigins[0]=*
cas.httpWebRequest.cors.allowMethods[0]=*
cas.httpWebRequest.cors.allowHeaders[0]=*
```

Here are my request headers and the response:

Request:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1975
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: JSESSIONID=117D9345E985D824E46…BF32; io=gLhCcBoZrfNcppioAAAB
Host: localhost:4200
Referer: https://localhost:4200/sales/proposals/dashboard
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

Response (Status Code - 403 Forbidden):

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-length: 56
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 16:39:14 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
x-frame-options: DENY
x-powered-by: Express
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

The angular service is running on `https://localhost:4200`.

The spring boot service is running on `https://localhost:8493`.

The CAS service is running on `https://localhost:8443`.

There are no error messages that I have seen in any of the logs.  I would like to be able to understand why a PUT request is forbidden, and then how to fix it so that a PUT request will also work.  Thanks!

**EDIT: Add Spring Boot Security Configuration**

```
<http pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
            <intercept-url pattern="/api/holidays" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/api/unit**" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

            <custom-filter ref="casAuthenticationFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/>

            <csrf/>         
    </http>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <!-- CAS Config -->
    <beans:bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <beans:property name="loginUrl" value="${cas.server.host.login_url}"/>
            <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
            <beans:property name="service" value="${app.server.host.url}login/cas"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
            <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
            <beans:property name="ticketValidator" ref="ticketValidator"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="key" value="Key"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsWrapper"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsWrapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetails"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <ldap-user-service id="userDetails"
        server-ref="ldapServer"
        group-search-base="ou=ERPGroups,OU=MyBusiness"
        group-search-filter="(member={0})"
        user-search-base="ou=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness"
        user-search-filter="(sAMAccountName={0})" />

    <ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="${ldap.urls}/${ldap.base}" manager-dn="${ldap.username}" manager-password="${ldap.password}" />

    <beans:bean id="ticketValidator" class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas30ServiceTicketValidator">
            <beans:constructor-arg value="${cas.server.host.url}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
        <authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

**EDIT: Add Angular Proxy Config**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target" : "https://localhost:8493",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "secure" : false
    }
}
```

Comment: 403 means forbidden, like if the user was not authenticated/allowed to access the method server side. I don't know much about CAS, but is the CAS cookie sent in the PUT request? (I see a session cookie and the 'io' cookie). If it's a cors issue, it'll be client side and you should see something if you fireup your browser's dev tools/debugger

Comment: Can you provide the security configuration that you are using on the spring boot server application?

Comment: I just spotted x-powered-by: Express
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block  Are you using a NodeJS Express proxy?

Comment: If there is CORS issue, refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is enforced by the browser, but in this case you are getting 403 from the server. As others have mentioned, your request seems to be missing the CSRF header and that's probably why the server is rejecting your request. I can't tell why this started happening when you switched to HTTPS, but I can tell you have `<csrf/>` in your configuration but no header to match.

To verify this theory, you can disable [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection by changing:

```
<csrf/>
```

to:

```
<csrf disabled="true"/>
```

Starting with Spring 4 CSRF protection is enabled by default so simply removing `<csrf/>` will not be enough.

Once you've confirmed CSRF was the issue and you no longer get 403, you should turn it back on in a way that [Angular supports](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection). It's an important protection that will protect your users. Angular expects a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` which it will send back with `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header. Those are configurable, but should match Spring's default if you're using latest Spring and latest Angular. Follow [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-cookie) to add:

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"/>
</http>
<b:bean id="tokenRepository"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository"
    p:cookieHttpOnly="false"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your spring boot security configuration, I see **csrf** has been enabled. But in your request I don't see any cookie `XSRF-TOKEN` and header `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. That is why the server is not accepting the request and the responding with **403** response.

Your browser probably is not creating SSL connection. This usually happens when the browser finds an incorrect certificate or a self signed certificate or a certificate signed by a Certification Authority which is not trusted.

If you are using chrome browser you can enable this for localhost for testing purpose by enabling `allow-insecure-localhost` property. Enter this URL in the address bar, click on **Enable** and restart Chrome.

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Refer this link for more details for enabling it in chrome and firefox.
https://improveandrepeat.com/2016/09/allowing-self-signed-certificates-on-localhost-with-chrome-and-firefox/

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I tried removing csrf from the spring boot config, as well as trying from Chrome with the insecure localhost enabled (had been using Firefox before), and I get the same response either way.

Comment: "As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with XML configuration" so simply removing it is not enough. You should disable it with `<csrf disabled="true"/>` to get it working. But once you prove it is CSRF, you should turn it back on and fix your Angular code to properly handle CSRF so your website is not left vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should have an X-XSRF-TOKEN token in your request header since csrf  is enabled in your security conf. 
For me this worked :

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
    }
```

Then extract a token

```
const token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
```

and add it to the header

```
this.http.post<any>(url, body, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)})
```

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP requests that potentially modify something on the server, like PUT, POST, DELETE and PATCH does not know whether they are allowed to execute the request if they have not been told in beforehand.

They can know by reading the headers of an earlier request that have allowed them to modify the requested resource, or they will fire an OPTIONS request just before. This is called a 'preflight' request.

If you have not implemented the OPTIONS method to respond with CORS headers, this is what you need to do.

Have a look [here](https://spring.io/understanding/CORS) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the informative resource.  A number of things I've read make it sound like the browser should automatically send the pre-flight request.  I am not seeing any kind of pre-flight request in the browser network debug tools.  Am I supposed to manually create it, or how can I force the browser to send the pre-flight request?

Comment: It is sent automatically, but you may need to handle it server-side. My question above regarding express is because if you are using a proxy you may not be doing CORS at all

Comment: I am using a proxy during development. In package.json, I have `start: ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json ...` and in that conf file I have `...target: https://localhost:8493 ...`.  So different ports are in use, which I assume would qualify as a different origin.

Comment: No, it doesn't as the origin is something the browser looks at, and it communicates through your Angular dev-server which forwards the request and adds its own headers before returning.

Comment: So if CORS is not an issue, why would the GET requests work, but PUT requests get a `Forbidden` response?

Comment: That is the interessting question. I can't provide a clear answer right now, because forwarding ssl requests are not trivial. There's an interesting thread here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4031 discussing some opportunities. Also the official docs says how you can modify headers in the proxy if needed. Can you post your proxy.config ? You should probably have 'changeOrigin': true  as a start

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue, My frontEnd is in Angular4 , Back-end in Spring and Authentication I used was JWT based authentication.I was getting this error for my POST request, but I guess it applies to PUT too, as both come under "not- so-simple request" (an Alias for pre-flight request).

My UI works for some time, and then I was getting following error:

Cannot load https://localhost:8080/myApp/services/stationCollection/viewCollected. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

After an Analysis, I came to know that pre-flight request is getting passed, with full success, it’s the main request that is getting denied the access to the server (you can check that in Network tab in chrome dev tools and get the detail) . The type of CORS request being sent is “not-so-simple requests”. The fact that, if you send the same request, to the same server with Rest Client/ curl, it works all fine.

When you browse this error in web, you find lost of solutions, All leading to configure CORS at server-side, but the fact that I had already implemented CORS.

**Possible Solution:**

All this led to me to find a solution for the same, and after much search, I found that there is a possible  hack / alternative for this problem, as best defined in the following blog:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cros-access-control-allow-origin-not-in-the-headers

The Blog basically asks you to create a middleware, between all the requests passed from UI to Front-end, and if you know your application is an Authentic one, add

```
myOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

in the middle ware. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul. When I watch the network tool, there are no preflight requests being sent.  Apparently when a proxy is in use, it is somehow treated differently.  But with no preflight request, I don't think this option will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this header on the server side `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

if that doesn't help you and other post request works as expected, I'm afraid some part of your code is wrong.

Comment: I tried adding this to my Rest Controller in Spring Boot like `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.update(input), headers, HttpStatus.OK);`, but it did not seem to make any difference.  It doesn't make sense to me how the code could be wrong if the only change is whether it is SSL or not.  Also, why would the response be `Forbidden`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this on your Spring Boot App?

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");

return new ResponseEntity<>(service.update(input), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

More readings can be found here https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 0):

Changing Spring config to allow CORS might not be a good idea. What I did was to install a nginx server and use it as a reverse proxy. Below is my sample nginx.conf:

```
# Spring backend
location /api
{
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8493;
}

# Angular front end
location /
{
  root www/apps;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```