# Angular 2 frontend not connecting with backend - AFTER DEPLOYMENT

Tags: angular, spring-boot, deployment

I have developed an angular2 project in http://www.demo.aranidhi.in
Backend for this application is developed in spring boot which is hosted in  http://env-7423163.cloud.cms500.com.
If i try to connect front and backend am getting this error

[image: Error image]

But this is working in developer machine... I dont know how. I think while exporting to war am missing something. Can you please guide me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error message, this is because you are making **cross-origin request**.

Before adding cross-origin header to your request from frontend, you can try a simple chrome extension [Allow-cross-allow-origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en).This should let you make request to the backend.

After confirming that above extension helped you to make your code work, then you can change your request and can add cross-origin headers to it.

Hope this will help!