# Angular + Spring mvc : Getting Invalid CORS request error when making server call

Tags: spring, angular, model-view-controller

when i tried to login from my angular login page. I am getting following. and response saying 'Invalid CORS request'.

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8088/myproduct/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8088
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:20
Date:Tue, 16 Jan 2018 09:59:47 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:WildFly/9
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1:8088
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36`enter code here`
```

Not getting what is the problem (where is the problem)? Please suggest.

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid this by adding an annotation in your service side. Something like this -

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:4200");

Answer (score -1):

Place @CrossOrigin annotation at the top of the @RequestMapping annotation

like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "postanswer", headers = "Accept=application/json;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<AnswerResult> PostAnswer(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
```

}