# Getting CORS error when sending data to JAVA post REST API in Angular 4

Tags: java, angular, rest, cors, http-status-code-415

I am sending reactive form data through post request to java restful web api but it shows me CORS error While same is working fine in GET request. I already set the CORS header in response of rest api.

**Angular Service Code :**

```
 private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    baseURL='http://127.0.0.1:8080/userInformation/rest/UserService';
    addData(formdata: any){
        var body = JSON.stringify(formdata);
           return this.http.post(this.baseURL+'/adduser',body)
                            .subscribe(
                           res => {
                            console.log(res);
                         },
                      err => {
                        console.log('Error occured');
                      }
          );


  }
```

**JAVA Rest API CODE :**

```
       @POST
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       @Path("/adduser")
       public Response createUser(String val){  
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           User user = gson.fromJson(val, User.class);
           userDao.insertUser(user);
           String result="SUCCESS";
           return Response.ok().entity(result)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                    .build();
       }
```

Header Description :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6ZVb.png)
I think when we are sending the data to rest api we need to set the CORS origin header to our angular code. How can I do this?

Comment: This is exact error:   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Do you really mean [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) errors? I think you do.

Comment: Did you get `403` response status code? Also refer this post's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Comment: No I am getting error code 500. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add filter for incoming request as below:

Create a filter CrossOrigin as below :

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class CrossOrigin implements ContainerResponseFilter {

     @Override
        public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest creq, ContainerResponse cresp) {

            cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");

            return cresp;
        }
}
```

And then register it in web.xml :

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.newgen.ap2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.newgen.ap2.CrossOrigin</param-value>
     </init-param>

  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it by using annotation on the Controller class declaration.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping({ "/controller" })
public class Controller {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without changing the backend by running Angular with a **proxy** configuration. More details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

*In a nutshell*:

1. Change your `baseUrl`'s port to 4200 (or whichever your Angular app runs on):

   ```
   baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:4200/userInformation/rest/UserService';
   ```
2. Create a *proxy.conf.json* file in the root of your Angular project with the content:

   ```
   {
     "/userInformation": {
       "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
       "secure": false
     }
   }
   ```
3. Run the Angular app with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

At this point your app runs on port 4200 and when you try to hit an endpoint containing `/userInformation`, it hijacks the URL and sends it to the target you set in your proxy configuration plus the rest of the path, so http://127.0.0.1:8080/userInformation/rest/UserService/addUser. By the way, if your endpoint is not up in your backend, the browser dev console will complain about that endpoint on port 4200, but the call really went to 8080.