# CORS policy issue while hitting the rest service(Spring Boot) from Angular5 Application

Tags: spring-boot, angular5

I am getting below error when I try to hit post service from Angular 5

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden) Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://xxxx/xxxx/services/exportVarianceHome' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Below is my interceptor configuration in Angular 5

```
import { Injectable, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()
export class HttpsRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const dupReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Authorization', 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true') });
    return next.handle(dupReq);
  }
};
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpsRequestInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
```

And Angular Post Call

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){
         getLookupDetails();
}

  getLookupDetails(){
    this.httpClient.get(this.servicsUrl).subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            console.log("JSON Response " + JSON.stringify(data));
          }
        )
     }
```

And the Cross origin Setup at server side (SpringBoot)

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.controller.gtm"})
public class BrokerValidationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BrokerValidationApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BrokerValidationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println(">=== Inside Cors Orgin Mapping addCorsMappings ===>");
        registry.addMapping("/services/**")
          .allowedOrigins("*")
          .allowedMethods("POST", "GET",  "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
          .allowedHeaders("*")
          .allowCredentials(true)
          .maxAge(4800);
    }

}
```

Comment: Using * for the origin is not always allowed. Try setting your client's host and port (if not port 80) in the server's header

Comment: My Angular UI is running in my local and springboot app is running in server so can i change like .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") ??

Comment: It dint work Carlo

Comment: CORS is difficult, no question. I've fought with this multiple times and Chrome is known to be more restrictive on this. Did you also supply the protocol? i.e. .allowedOrigins("`http://localhost:4200`")

Comment: yes, I have added http

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290