# Spring security and angular 401 error when trying some requests

Tags: java, angular, spring, security

I have a restful application Angular/Jee.
I'm using spring Boot and security.

All request are working well from `localhost:8080`

From angular (`localhost:4200/`), log in/log out and registrer requests are working well BUT when i try another request like `localhost:8080/getUserBooks`
it fail with `401 error`

**NOTE:
- I tried to diseable CORS from Chrome, but didn't work.
- I read a lot of same problems but no solution has worked for my situation.
- I already added the annotation @CrossOrigin("*")  to my rest controller**

Here is my WebSecurity configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL)
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager())).sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Comment: I'm usign RestController not a servlet. Thank you

Comment: Yes I'll work for the same, Please refer the question of that link, You just need to add that class in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i added the class but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

You must have to allow the cross origin for  port number :8080