# Spring boot with Spring Security (+ Angular) returns 401 error

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

My Spring boot (Spring Security) app returns a 401 error on trying to login using http://localhost:4200/login

I don't seem to figure out why I am getting the 401 error. Similar configurations seemed to have worked in some examples I saw online.

**Here is the Request result:**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/account/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 08:05:37 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm", Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic Y2pAaG90bWFpbC5jb206Y2hyaXMx
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

**In Spring, WebConfig.java looks like:**

```
package com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.configurations;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.services.AppUserDetailsService;

@Configurable
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
// Modifying or overriding the default spring boot security.
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

    // This method is for overriding the default AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
    // We can specify how the user details are kept in the application. It may
    // be in a database, LDAP or in memory.
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
    }

    // this configuration allow the client app to access the this api
    // all the domain that consume this api must be included in the allowed o'rings
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

            }
        };
    }

    // This method is for overriding some configuration of the WebSecurity
    // If you want to ignore some request or request patterns then you can
    // specify that inside this method
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        /*
         * web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
         * "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html/**",
         * "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
         * "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
         */
    }

    // This method is used for override HttpSecurity of the web Application.
    // We can specify our authorization criteria inside this method.
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                // starts authorizing configurations
                .authorizeRequests()
                // ignoring the guest's urls "
                .antMatchers("/account/register", "/account/login", "/logout", "/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html/**",
                        "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html#/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html#/job-portal-controller/**")
                .permitAll()

                // authenticate all remaining URLS
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
                /*
                 * "/logout" will log the user out by invalidating the HTTP Session, cleaning up
                 * any {link rememberMe()} authentication that was configured,
                 */
                .logout().permitAll().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "POST")).and()
                // enabling the basic authentication
                .httpBasic().and()
                // configuring the session on the server
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and()
                // disabling the CSRF - Cross Site Request Forgery
                .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

**My Spring AccountController.java looks like this:**

```
package com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.controllers;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.entities.User;
import com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.services.UserService;
import com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.utils.CustomErrorType;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    // request method to create a new account by Job Seeker
        @CrossOrigin
        @PostMapping(value = "/register")
        public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
            System.out.println("/register called with " + newUser.toString());
            // check email to only allow unregistered emails
            if (userService.findUserByUsername(newUser.getUsername()) != null) {
                System.out.println("username already exists " + newUser.getUsername());
                return new ResponseEntity(
                        new CustomErrorType("User with username " + newUser.getUsername() + "already exists "),
                        HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }
            newUser.setRole("Job Seeker");

            return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.save(newUser), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }


        // request method to create a new account by a Recruiter
        @CrossOrigin
        @PostMapping(value = "/registerAsRecruiter")
        public ResponseEntity<?> createRecruiter(@RequestBody User newUser) {
            if (userService.findUserByUsername(newUser.getUsername()) != null) {
                System.out.println("username already exists " + newUser.getUsername());
                return new ResponseEntity(
                        new CustomErrorType("User with username " + newUser.getUsername() + "already exists "),
                        HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }
            newUser.setRole("Recruiter");

            return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.save(newUser), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

        // this is the login api/service
        @CrossOrigin
        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public Principal user(Principal principal) {

            System.out.println("user logged "+principal);
            return principal;
        }
}
```

**And I also have a CORS filter MyCORSFilter.java working on another path (/api/*)**

```
package com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.configurations;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
//@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/api/*")
public class MyCORSFilter implements Filter {


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

**And a SwaggerConfig.java for Swagger**

```
package com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{
    @Bean
    public Docket produceApi(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .apiInfo(apiInfo())
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.neha.jobportal.jobportalbackend.controllers"))
    .build();
}
// Describe your apis
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
    .title("Job Portal Rest APIs")
    .description("This page lists all the rest apis exposed by the Job Portal Backend.")
    .version("1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    .build();
}

}
```

Comment: try renaming MyCORSFilter to CorsFilter or provide the name in @Configuration. 
see docs for detail. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors--

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Comment: Was able to reproduce the issue with the files you posted. I get the same error