# Serving Spring REST API from Nginx, issues with CORS and CSRF

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security

I've been struggling with this for 8 hours already and I realized that this is not something that I can come up with on my own.

I'm trying to serve a REST API implemented with Spring Boot using Nginx on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu. I have implemented a simple JWT authentication along with passing a CSRF token on every request. I have a frontend implemented with ReactJS. The whole system worked fine when I deployed it to Heroku, but back then backend served the frontend as well, so CORS was not much of an issue really. I'm supposed to do a deployment for a "client", who's webhotel does not support Spring Boot, therefore I need to serve frontend and backend in different locations.

### Basically I'm running into multiple issues:

- My frontend code does not find the CSRF token when the app is opened
- If I (for testing purposes) don't even try to pass the CSRF token on logon, I run into CORS error: *"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ip.of.my.droplet.on.digitalocean/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://url.of.my.frontend.on.heroku.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."*

I've been Googling and trying different kinds of configurations for so long that I don't even have an idea if my fixes actually are causing more problems or just not doing anything.

### My Spring Security configuration

```
        http
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and()
                .requiresChannel()
                    .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
                    .requiresSecure()
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

### Spring CORS configuration

```
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins([URL to the frontend for testing purposes])
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH")
                .allowedHeaders("authorization, content-type, content-length, xsrf-token, credentials")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .exposedHeaders("xsrf-token")
                .maxAge(3600);
```

### Nginx service configuration

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        server_name [IP of my DigitalOcean droplet here];

        location /api {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
             proxy_set_header Origin [URL to the frontend deployed on Heroku for testing purposes];
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
             proxy_pass_header X-XSRF-TOKEN;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name [IP of my DigitalOcean droplet here];

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

### Axios configuration on frontend

```
  const CSRF_TOKEN = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+)'))[1];

  instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: '[ip-address of my DigitalOcean droplet]/api',
    headers: { 
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PATCH, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
    }
  });
```

I'm very beginner here, so I'm not even sure if any of this is right at all. I just know that it worked when it all was deployed to Heroku, so atleast some of it should be right.

Comment: If I understand well, durring your tests your front URL is `https://vc-sales.herokuapp.com`, and you back URL is `https://206.81.27.39/api/auth/login`. If I'm right your `cors` conf might be `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://vc-sales.herokuapp.com").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH").allowedHeaders("authorization, content-type, content-length, xsrf-token, credentials").allowCredentials(true).exposedHeaders("xsrf-token").maxAge(3600);`

Comment: @Zorglube mmeh, there was an attempt to hide my Droplet IP/frontend URL... :D But yes, that's exactly what my cors configuration looks like.

Comment: Ok, and so... It is working now ?

Comment: @Zorglube no it's not, your suggestion is exactly how my CORS configuration looks like (I just had the URLs and IPs removed from it), thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Did you tryed with `regitry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://localhost").`

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Comment: @Zorglube yes I did.

Comment: @hrdkisback - That did not solve my problem at all.