# has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

My angular code

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const nextReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
                .set('Pragma', 'no-cache')
                .set('Expires', 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT')
                .set('If-Modified-Since', '0')
                .set('Authorization', 'secret')
                .set('client-id', 'test')


        });

        return next.handle(nextReq).timeout(220000).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

My Java service code :

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler)
    {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin,cache-control,client-id,expires,if-modified-since, pragma");


        String clientId = request.getHeader("client-id");

}
```

After running the application, I am getting this error and client id is coming null - 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

I have added all required headers .

Please help

below is my network call

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkRUC.png)

Comment: the CORS should be handled at the server, also make sure you are passing correct headers from client as required by what you have configured at the server

Comment: https://dev.to/effingkay/cors-preflighted-requests--options-method-3024

Comment: Probably the OPTIONS request is a 404 - have you looked at the network tab?

Comment: can you inspect you network call in chrome and check if the headers are passed properly

Comment: please check the image attached

Comment: its giving 500 error code

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 0):

Probably the probleme came out from the server side (your back-end) , but you can try this for puttiong it on clear way.
would you pleare try to inject a bean that can provide you the cros configuration :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chaine)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        System.out.println("****************** CORS Configuration Completed *******************");
        chaine.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

At the main class, try to inject the bean like this :

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean crosFilterRegistration(){
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CORSFilter());
        registrationBean.setName("CORS Filter");
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Hope this would be useful for you or any one else :)