# CORS blocked Angular 7 and Spring 5

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm running a Spring 5 with Spring Security and Angular 7 project and trying to wire the frontend but keep getting this err message. I should note the projects are two different directories on my computer

OS backend > spring

OS frontend > angular

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource.
```

I've gone through a bunch of threads here on stackoverflow but none would help.

From what i've gathered the issue is my spring security config

**SPRING SECURITY FILE**

```java
package com.starter_kit.auth;

import com.starter_kit.auth.Auth.CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.starter_kit.auth.Company.CompanyRepo;
import com.starter_kit.auth.Users.UserRepo;
import com.starter_kit.auth.Users.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // code

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard/").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("/**"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","DELETE","PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Spring Controller

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/login", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public UserDetails login(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.loadUserByUsername(user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

and my ANGULAR TS HTTP CALL

```
private loginAuth: string = "http://localhost:8080/login";
  public headers = new HttpHeaders({ "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true" })

  public loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(
      this.loginAuth,
      user,
      { headers: this.headers }
    );
  }
```

any help would be great

Comment: Read your error message carefully.

Comment: I've tried adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the header object in angular, but still got an error

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Comment: @hrdkisback thanks this got me going somewhere but still can't seem to get to login. Think the issue might be on the Angular side

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides an out of the box solution to exclude OPTIONS requests from authorization checks

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().authorizeRequests() ...

}
```

The cors() method will add the Spring-provided CorsFilter to the application context which in turn bypasses the authorization checks for OPTIONS requests.