# Best way to treat allow access-control-allow-origin in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am developping an app using angular in the front and spring boot in the backend but when i send requests from front to backend i got allow access-control-allow-origin error i have added in my controller @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") and it works.So i want to know if it's a good idea to do that or not ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 1):

CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) should be allowed in back end So yes do it in spring boot and you can't treat it in Angular front end.

The @CrossOrigin annotation enables cross-origin requests only for this specific method.
So it's your choice.