# CORS error with Ionic App and standalone angular app connecting to Spring backend

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, ionic4

My backend is running on SpringBoot and I have enabled CORS using the filter method, this is how my `SpringCORSFilter` looks like :

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

@Override
public void destroy() {}

}
```

I have 2 front end applications, and both of them have a similar HTTP header setup.
which look like this :

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With',
          });
```

In my standalone angular app I am seeing these issues only on the firefox or the mobile browser, but no issues at all with the chrome browser.

I have attached an image with the issue that I am [image: seeing].

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

EDIT 1: So I have asked a couple of users to test out both the core app as well my standalone app and we are seeing the CORS issue in both the cases.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 1):

So this one took quite some time to get done, and I realised a couple of things are really important especially when attempting to solve a CORS issue.

- Take a deep breath and relax; it may/may not take 3-4 days to solve 
  the issue but it definitely take some time and having the right plan
  in place would help you solve the issue. Having an environment where the issue is recreated and is consistently available is also important. I realised the issue was occurring across all the front end applications and across all browsers.
- The issue could because your backend is not configured correctly or even your front end.
- Here are a couple of things I have to check from the backend perspective:
- The backend is actually up and running.
- In case of spring-boot if there any annotations which are preventing any api calls. After getting rid of `@EnableWebMvc` and redeploying the project the API calls were successful.
- Changes to Spring boot to enable CORS

  `@Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
          return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
              @Override
              public void addCorsMappings( CorsRegistry registry) {
                  registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","OPTIONS").allowedOrigins("*")
                          .allowedHeaders("*").maxAge(-1)   // add maxAge
                          .allowCredentials(false);
              }
          };
      }`
- From the front end too; to ensure that every API call had a header associated.

Every CORS error has an explanation and it is important to understand that thoroughly. In our case, it was more with the SSL certificate that could not be trusted across all browsers. This [ssl checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/) was used to verify the SSL certificate and changes were made accordingly to deploy the SSL certificate to the backend. 
With that, we were able to overcome the SSL issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use native HTTP module for ajax calls. this is the link
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http