# Spring Boot : Access to XMLHttpRequest at BACK_END' from origin FRONTEND has been blocked by CORS policy even when @CrossOrigin is used

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-restcontroller

I have a restcontroller which is marked with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")`. However my request is getting blocked by CORS policy despite having the `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")` at controller level .

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/foo/bar' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below is the outline of the code

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;


    @PostMapping(path="/foo/bar")
    public ResponseEntity<RespObject> dosomething(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) 
    .
    .
    .
    //somecode
    }
}
```

The api is getting called from the Angular Ui app .

**APIService.ts**

```
create(candidateInititationDto: CandidateInitiationDTO) {
    return this.httpClient.post<RespObject>(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/foo/bar",
      requestDTO
    );
  }
```

1. This is the only controller in this micro service as of now and I have tried all possible combinations of @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*") , @CrossOrigin,@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") at controller level and method level.

This is the only Micro service where @CrossOrigin is not working . It is working fine in all other micro services.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to solve the issue. Apparently while refactoring the code the package name got changed and it wasn't picking up by package scan. Spring instead of throwing 404 , it was failing at preflight request.

Steps I followed to debug .

1. Remove all the other controllers
2. Keep the one controller and method trying to debug.
3. When I tried hitting it with postman , it failed at that point we got to know why it failed .
4. To prevent this disaster from happening again Integration test has been put in place
5. The `@CrossOrigin(origins = "", allowedHeaders = "") ,@CrossOrigin` .All the above options will do the job .
6. Most secure way is to have a global CORSS filter and whitelist orings and make it configurable .

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this Bean to your Controller:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

For example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeRestController {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;


    @PostMapping(path="/foo/bar")
    public ResponseEntity<RespObject> dosomething(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) 
    .
            .
            .
    //somecode
}
```

Comment: Nope Still getting the same issue even with this approach .

Answer (score 1):

Try removing origins  and allowedHeaders and simply use

**@CrossOrigin**

this would also allow all the requests.

Comment: Could you please paste complete code of controller class, along with import statements.

Comment: I don't think complete code of controller is necessary here . I have added import statements in the question .