# OAuth2 Authentication Java Spring error in Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, oauth-2.0

I have implemented oAuth2 in java spring. 
when I send request from postman with basic auth i get token in response. But when I send it from angular it return 401.

please check the attached code and images.

```
package com.spring.rest.spring_rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        //      super.configure(endpoints);
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
//      super.configure(security);
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
//      super.configure(clients);
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials","password")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read","write","trust")
            .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
            .secret("secret");
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Angular Code:
DataService.ts

```
login(loginPayload) {
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('my-trusted-client:secret'),
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/' + 'oauth/token', loginPayload, {headers});
  }
```

Login.ts

```
const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', this.f.username.value)
      .set('password', this.f.password.value)
      .set('grant_type', 'password');

    this.dataService.login(body.toString()).subscribe(data => {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
      this.router.navigate(['user-profile']);
    }, error => {
        alert(error.error.error_description)
    });
```

Comment: Can you add the console out?

Comment: Are you getting CORS issue in console?

Comment: It seems that you're passing your `HttpParams` as a request body and not URL params. You should pass them into the `http.post()` options (like `headers`), but do not send `body.toString()` to your service, only `body`, as the options will wait for `HttpParams` object

Comment: I think headers should be `{ headers: headers}` instead of `{headers}`.

Comment: in postman you are sending user and password and url params but in your ts you are sending in body. your dataService.ts should be like this.
`this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/' + 'oauth/token?gratType=' + loginPayload.grant_type + '&password=' + loginPayload.password + '&username=' + loginPayload.username, loginPayload, {headers});`

Comment: @hrdkisback yess! but that is allowed from server.

Comment: @FarhatZaman tried your code but still same error

Comment: ok got it. try this way `const params = '&gratType=password&username=' + this.f.username.value +  '&password=' + this.f.password.value;`; and then pass params to `dataService.log(params)` without using `toString()` and don't change the dataService.ts file and try. hope it will work.

Comment: @FarhatZaman Hey even this is not working. getting cors error too

Comment: Refer this post for CORS errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290