# Springboot hot reload angular 8 during development

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I am creating an application with Springboot and Angular 8. I am new to Springboot. My plan is to build the frontend (`ng build` - that will be called from `mvn clean package`) inside the `src/main/resources`.

The problem is that if I do it like that, I cannot hot reload when some changes happens on the frontend.
Is there a best practice how to build such an application? My intention is to package the backend and the frontend in the same `jar` file but in the same time I need to see changed files in the fontend directly on the browser.

On the other side, if I start the frontend (during development) with `ng serve` then it will not work because of cross origin issues.

Comment: Why do you want to package backend and frontend together? I think that it's better to keep them separate. Your problem is related to the cross origin? Note that is better to configure it in the backend application.

Comment: What do you mean exactly "to keep them separate"? Do u mean during development or also in prod. They are separate but at the end they will be packaged in the same `JAR`. My problem is that if I start them separately (only during development) then I get cross origin issues. I think the answer from @Florian is a good solution I should check.

Comment: For CORS issue refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During development, I strongly advise you not to bundle the frontend with your backend (spring boot), it will make things much more complicated and harder to develop. As I know of, there's no way in spring boot to "hot reload" the files in the static resources. And even if, how would you re-compile your angular project first? This is, with mvn package, done at compile time, not runtime.

To solve your problem I would do the following:

- Use `ng serve` while developing the frontend
- Start your spring boot backend standalone (without a bundled frontend)

To get over the CORS issue you mentioned, I would use the proxy feature, which angular provides out-of-the-box:

1. Add the proxy configuration file to the `serve` section of your angular.json:

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "client:build",
    "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"   <------- proxy config
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
    }
  }
},
```

2. Then, add the proxy configuration to your project:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

You may need to change the configuration based on your local port setup and stuff. When you do a request to `http://localhost:4200/api/any/endpoint`, it will be proxied to `http://localhost:8080/api/any/endpoint` without violating any CORS rule of your browser.

Then, your frontend should be configured to do requests to the domain it is currently on, or you can have a different environment file for prod and development, where you can simply change the URL.

Comment: Where should I put the second part of the proxy configuration? You said, put it to your project, but can you please be more specific? Thnx.

Comment: You create a new file proxy.conf.json next to your package jsonw ith the contents mentioned in my answer. That should be it :)

Comment: I tried what you said but I still get an "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/hello. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).".
You can check the POC project hier: https://github.com/Elio-Shyti/springangular

Comment: That's probably because you still make your requests to localhost:8080, while (like I wrote) you need to do them against localhost:4200 (or whatever the port of the angular webserver is) :) If you show me your frontend project as well, I probably can point you to the right position.

Comment: Yes, you are right! That was the problem. Now it works perfect. (you can find the frontend inside the repo under springangular/src/myapp/ - do you think the structure is ok?). I will push also the fix. Thank you!

Comment: @Floarin- but I still have a question. If I make a request against localhost:4200, that will work good in development environment but will fail in production. Is there anyway this change between development and production be to done automatically?

Comment: You could use angulars environment variables for that: https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/ You could define your URL for development differently from the one defined in the environment.prod.ts. Or, even better, make the URLs you query from your app relative to the current window.location (instead of lcoalhost:4200/api/example use /api/example) and the app will use the current URL for serving the requests. Depending on your deployment mechanism, solution 1 or 2 might be better :)

Comment: You've brighten my day! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remove the cross origin issue during development:
Disable cross origin check in your browser.
Start chrome with certain parameters, e.g. [Run Chrome browser without CORS](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)
or add an extension to your browser, e.g.[Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

And of course: Don´t deactivate the cross origin check when you are not developing. It´s a security feature protecting you from harm.

Comment: Ok, I think this is a reasonable answer. But I don't want that each developer do the same think on his browser. I am looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score -1):

For the solution, you can enable cors origin from the server-side in your spring boot application so your cross-origin issue will resolve.

You can enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) from either individual controllers or globally. The following topics describe how to do so:

1. Controller Method CORS Configuration
2. Global CORS configuration

   1. Controller Method CORS Configuration

You can define @CrossOrigin anotation in controller level.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600)
```

2. Global CORS configuration

JavaConfig
Enabling CORS for the whole application is as simple as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

**Creating the Application Class**

```
package com.example.cors;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceCorsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceCorsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: This will ship the CORS headers in the production deployed product as well, which is probably not what you want to have, even if these are only localhost URLs.

Comment: For the configuration level, you can define the environment setup in your application and based on the environment dynamic URL you can define in your application.yml file