# CORS issue when running Spring Boot with Angular using @CrossOrigin at controller level

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm getting a CORS error when running calls to the Spring Boot 2.6.4 web service

[image]

Here is the code in Angular 13:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'
});
let options = { headers: headers };

this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:8080/country/available", options).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I have the controller annotated with `@CrossOrigin` at the controller level:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("country")
public final class CountryController {

    private final transient CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    public CountryController(final CountryService countryService) {
        this.countryService = countryService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/available")
    public List<Country> getAvailableCountries() {
        return countryService.getAvailableCountries();
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788969/angular2-spring-boot-allow-cross-origin-on-put/46789290#46789290

Answer (score -1):

Try this
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",  allowedHeaders = "*" ,maxAge = 3600)`

or you can do it in the security configuration as http.cros()