# CORS policy conflict in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm new to spring boot and I implemented some basic REST apis using spring boot. And when I tried to call those api using react I've got an error calling some CORS policies. Then I found a solution to that problem, And all my api end point working correctly except the login api call. I get the same error calling:

[image]

Here is my web security java class.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().cors().and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager())).sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    public AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/users/login");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

And here is my example controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}", 
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public UserRest getUser(@PathVariable String id) {

        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();

        UserDto userDto = userService.getUserByUserId(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDto, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, 
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public UserRest createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) {

        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();

        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, userDto);

        UserDto createUser = userService.createUser(userDto);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(createUser, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this problem and I really need some help. I've tried some answers given in stackoverflow as similar to my problem. But that didn't solve my problem. Mt spring boot version is 2.1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing the issue because,you have allowed cors on your backend from port 8080, but your react is up in port 3000 on local.So , springboot will not accept the request as it is coming from a different port address.

**Method 1 :**

You could get away with this by using the annotation like :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", maxAge = 3600)
```

Since you are using springboot , you can also use the following global config to define which all domains have access to your backend.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST") //or allow all as you like
                    .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                    .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                    .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
             }
        };
    }
}
```

and if you are still having issues , **it might be because the spring security is not adding the CORS headers** like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your **response header**. In that case , you can define a custom CORS filter and add it to the spring security so that the CORS response headers are set for all spring security endpoints . You can create a filter bean like :

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 180);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

**since you are using spring security** you could also add the CORS configuration along with spring security like :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
            //other configurations that you want
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        //or any domain that you want to restrict to 
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        //Add the method support as you like
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new     UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Spring security will take up the CORS configuration even if you provide it like in method 1 as per my knowledge.But , in spring documentation they have provided this way of registering CORS with spring security as well.

In your **console log** that you have attached it is said that the pre flight check failed because of http status returned is not OK .So , can you try registering cors like method 2 and have a filter added so that the headers are added correctly in response. Springboot is blocking the pre flight check when the login page is accessed. You need to get your cors setup properly with the spring security to allow login page to be accessed from a dfferent port.

Confirm that your login page `/login` mapping have CORS allowed

Official [Doc](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#spring-boot-integration)
Reference [Doc](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight)

Comment: I tried all of the method. But the result is same. Only login api can't be accessed through react

Comment: In your console log that you have attached it is said that the pre flight check failed because of http status returned is not OK .So , can you try registering cors like method 2 and have a filter added so that the headers are added correctly in response. Springboot is blocking the pre flight check when the login page is accessed. You need to get your cors setup properly with the spring security to allow login page to be accessed from a dfferent port.

Comment: Then it says that : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Set the following in springboot response header and it shoulld work : Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: In my answer above , i have provided how to create a custom CORS filter , just register the CORS filter in your spring security configuration .Sometimes * is not recognized as origin by some browsers like edge in such cases try adding http://localhost:3000 to your list of origin.

Comment: You can refer this for similar case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864171/angular-2-spring-boot-login-cors-problems

Comment: Happy to be of help 

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

#### Update

you could also do the below,

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        filterRegistration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return filterRegistration;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Avi. But my problem was solved. Thanks by the way

Comment: what was the solution?