# Spring Boot - Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Tags: spring-boot, angular6

I have this mapping:

```
User 1----------------------------* Expertises
```

I'm using the controller SpringBoot, My contoller is

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:6227")
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class UserController
{

    @PostMapping("/signup/{expertises}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpForm signUpRequest, @PathVariable List<String> expertises)
    {
    }
}
```

I add the annotation `@CrossOrigin` to all the repositories

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:6227"}, methods = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.DELETE }, maxAge = 3600)
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

The main class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJwtAuthenticationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJwtAuthenticationApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configurer()
    {
          return new WebMvcConfigurer()
          {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
                {
                  registry.addMapping("/*")
                      .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:6227");
                }
          };
    }

}
```

I added the file **MyConfiguration** (as Sir `Ananthapadmanabhan` proposed)

[image]

**Front-End (Angular6)**

So I want to add a list of expertises to one user using this method:

```
 onSubmit()
        {
            this.submitted = true;
            console.log('---------SelectedExpertise:' + this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox);
            this.userService.signUpUser(this.user,
                                        this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox)
                            .subscribe(data => console.log("---------------Create user:" + data)
                            ,error => console.log(error));

            this.user = new User();
        }
```

where

```
signUpUser(value: any, listExp: String[]): Observable<Object>
    {
        return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/signup/${listExp}`, value);
    }
```

I can't do that cause adding the list of expertises. That produces **this error**
 [image: this error]

Have you please any idea about solving that ?.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide your spring boot version? and also a screenshot of OPTION call from chrome.

Comment: Hello Sir @YogeshPrajapati, thanks for your reply, `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated on the console; it was a problem with **CORS**.
But in reality, it wasn't.

In fact, this bug is caused by a bad use of **localStorage** with front-end:
the list of strings have to be called like that:

```
var storedExpertises = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("explib"));
```

and not like that:

```
localStorage.getItem("explib")
```

Big thanks Sir @Ananthapadmanabhan for your help and advices.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled **CORS** for the endpoint `http://localhost:4200` on port address `4200`. But it seems you are running the angular 6 app separately on local and the request is being made from the port address `6227` , which might be causing the issue  since the CORS policy that you have enabled only allows same origin. Try adding the following in CORS :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:6227")
```

and if you are still having issues with , `Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`  then check this post :

[CORS policy conflict in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759527/cors-policy-conflict-in-spring-boot/56765503#56765503)

Comment: Hello Sir @Ananthapadmanabhan, I made modification for all the files `@CrossOrigin(origins =  {"http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:6227"}`. So, **CORS** is enabled for 2 endpoints `http://localhost:4200` and `http://localhost:6227`, but still got error.

Comment: Also, I'd like to tell you that **BEFORE**, all is worked with success. This exception appears **AFTER** the use of `List<String> expertises`.

Comment: @Jolia Why don't use use a request param or request body to map the expertices rather than a path variable. If you are expecting multiple values in path variable then change it to use request param, you can have complex objects mapped as request params.

Comment: @Jolia Could you please attach the request and reponse headers  and response for your angular ajax call, like a screenshot of your console for example . Also, did you check the link that i provided in the answer , it's a similar issue .

Comment: Hello @Ananthapadmanabhan, I changed `@PathVariable List<String> expertises` to `@RequestParam List<String> expertises`, but still got the same issue. Once I remove it, all is work as well. So the problem is the add of `List<String> expertises`. But I can't know the cause. have you please any idea ?. Thanks

Comment: Oh i thought this was a CORS issue, seems like this is related to something else. Did you verify if the request is reaching your controller method properly or if there are any issues with mapping your request at the backend ?

Comment: Hello Sir @Ananthapadmanabhan, I found it. It wasn't a problem with CORS. In fact, the list of strings have to be called like that `var storedExpertises = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("explib"));` and not like that `localStorage.getItem("explib")`. Sir, could you please tell me how can I put the answer ?. Have I to answer my question ?. Big Big Big thanks for your attention. But as you see, the error as indicated is not related to CORS. It's a bad use of **localStorage**.

Answer (score 0):

Even through you have enabled the CORS. The requests from different ports will not go through. You need to enable **HTTP.OPTIONS**.