# CORS Issue during preflight browser request

Tags: spring-boot, cors, preflight, cross-origin-read-blocking

While trying to connect to my Rest APIs via Angular, I am running into what seems to be a fairly straight forward CORS issue:

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mserverIP:port/apicontext/getsitebyuserid/userId. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).*

My APIs are setup in Springboot and I have already tried following:

1. Set up **@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")** annotation at class and method levels. Also enabled GET, POST, OPTIONS for cross origin as well as allowed for all the headers.
2. Setup the  added CORS configuration globally with following code:

   ```
   httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
   httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD");

   httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "7200");
   httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
           "Content-Type, X-Requested-With, accept, authorization, Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
   ```
3. Tried it via proxy authentication (authentication being used is JWT).

This piece of information might be vital: for an unauthenticated API, the CORS issue doesn't happen but for the protected routes, it returns 403. The problem for protected routes happen even if I have not set authentication header to true.

Also, I have noticed earlier that during preflight, its combination of 2 headers that's causing the issue. If I send origin: http://localhost:4200 and Access-Control-Request-Method: GET it errors out. But if I sends one of the headers it works. During the OPTIONS request, if there's a request header called origin, the request fails. If I remove origin from postman it works.

Comment: look like you cross not working properly. try this way

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561352/8403689

Comment: @Imranmadbar- that worked like a charm. Thanks mate!!

Comment: well @Charan sounds good, so you may push an upvote there.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you are using spring security then you can get rid of the class level annotations and handle the CORS configuration globally in your security configuration class like :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
     http.
     cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/Signup").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), customUserDetailService));
}


@Bean   
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200")); //or * if you want to allow all 
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("custom-header1", "custom-header2"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
    return source; 
}
```

Secondly, you don't need the cors filter to manually add the response headers to every request because if you configure the cors configuration correctly , springboot will automatically add all the necessary headers in response through the `CorsFilter` . So, if you are using cors with spring security it is easier to us the provided filter with your configurations. Also, ensure that the springboot auto-configuration is working for you as using annotation `@EnableWebMvc` will disable the auto-configurations and in that case you will have to handle cors using filter probably.

Comment: I have already added CORS configuration globally as I mentioned in my second point but issue persists. And also, if use this: antMatchers("/**").permitAll(); it will simply override security of all the system.

Comment: @Charan You could have your spring security configured as you want, I was just demonstrating a simple setup in my sample code just focusing on the cors part.

Comment: @Charan If you have a glabal setup already.Try removing the class level configuration, the filter that you added and just provide the global configuration with the cors bean configured correctly and try again. Also please share your global configuration for analysis.