# Zuul gateway error with Content-Type: multipart/form-data API

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-2

We moved our project to spring boot 2, and getting the CORS error in the API which sending the **Content-Type: multipart/form-data**.
It was working fine with old version.

For CORS we have disabled it, putting the below code.

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
                        .exposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");

            }
        };
    }
```

All the API was working fine with old version, but now as we moved in spring boot 2, the apis where **Content-Type: application/json**  is working fine.
But in below API throwing the cors error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://{MyIP}:8080/users/v1/admin/uploadArticleData' from origin
>   'http://{MyIP}:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

OPTION API:- 
[image]

Post API:-
[image]

Some issue wiht my Zuul gateway, its throwing below error when calling **Content-Type: multipart/form-data;** API.
Error:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert form data
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.FormBodyWrapperFilter$FormBodyRequestWrapper.buildContentData(FormBodyWrapperFilter.java:207) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.FormBodyWrapperFilter$FormBodyRequestWrapper.getContentType(FormBodyWrapperFilter.java:159) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getContentType(ServletRequestWrapper.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext.getContentType(ServletRequestContext.java:74) ~[commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar!/:1.3.3]
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(FileUploadBase.java:77) ~[commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar!/:1.3.3]
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:71) ~[commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar!/:1.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.isMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1164) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1011) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 93 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "text": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:534) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:519) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.RequestContentDataExtractor.extractFromMultipartRequest(RequestContentDataExtractor.java:128) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.RequestContentDataExtractor.extract(RequestContentDataExtractor.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.FormBodyWrapperFilter$FormBodyRequestWrapper.buildContentData(FormBodyWrapperFilter.java:193) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "text": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:197) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:531) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The problem is actually a 500 error. Look at the part of your screen capture that says **Status Code**.

Comment: The header is missing the CORS accept headers which might be causing the issue . Similar post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759527/cors-policy-conflict-in-spring-boot/56765503#56765503