# Basic HTTP Authentication block all API Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I using Spring Boot and Angular for my project and I created the basic authentication with Basic HTTP Authentication. I have the block only 5 API call when the user is not authenticated, but for the current implementation, I get the all API calls blocked.

This is my Authentication service in the Angular :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  // BASE_PATH: 'http://localhost:8080'
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser'

  public username: String;
  public password: String;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  authenticationService(username: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.get(`api/v1/basicauth`,
      { headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) } }).pipe(map((res) => {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
      }));
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)
  }

  registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username)
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    this.username = null;
    this.password = null;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return false
    return true
  }

  getLoggedInUserName() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return ''
    return user
  }
}
```

This is my secyrity configuration in Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().

                authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("hej").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Comment: **I get the all API calls blocked**  What does it  mean? Attach screenshots of console error http response status/ server logs. Question with Incomplete info. Update question with sufficient info.

Comment: As your question is not clear can't give solution definitely. But try this and let me know. `http.csrf().disable()
   .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
   .and().httpBasic();`

Comment: Maybe this might be a related post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759527/cors-policy-conflict-in-spring-boot/56765503#56765503