# How to handle CORS error in Spring Boot, AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, cors

I am implementing a simple authentication program using AngularJS frontend and Spring Boot backend. I am facing an issue while sending the login request. When the relavent request sent, following error prints in the console

Error:-

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/rest/users/user' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
POST http://localhost:8080/rest/users/user net::ERR_FAILED
```

Same error occurred when sending the request for **registration** function. Then I found a solution of adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` to the controller. It fixed the error occured during the registration.
Now the problem is even though I have written the login method in the same controller, it gives me the error while trying to log in and will not gives any error if I try to register new user.

Below is the implementation of the backend

Repository :-

```
import com.app.cashier.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import java.util.List;
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<User> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Resource :-

```
package com.app.cashier.resource;

import com.app.cashier.model.User;
import com.app.cashier.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") //<------------ I addded @CrossOrigin
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public List<User> getAll(){
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/user")                          //<----- Login function. This still gives the above error
    public List<User> getUser(@RequestBody final User user){
        return usersRepository.findByUserName(user.getUserName());
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/load")                          //<----- Registration function. This gives no error after adding @CrossOrigin
    public List<User> persist(@RequestBody final User user){
        usersRepository.save(user);
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

AngularJS frontend request

```
    login(userName) {
        console.log(userName)

        return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8080/rest/users/user`, { userName })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                console.log(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

How can I overcome this issue. Massive thanks!

Comment: Try to put nginx in front of the two applications and reverse proxy them in order to make them available under a common URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the `@CrossOrigin` annotation at the controller level should enable cross origin for all the methods under that controller.lar request so it might be because of some additional headers that you are adding for that particular request so try like :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class UserResource {
//Your code
}
```

If still having issues then Could you share the url and the headers that you are using to login the new user ?. Also , try having a global cors configuration instead of a controller level one and provide fine grained properties like the methods that you want to expose. Provide the following in a configuration class :

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }
    };
}
```

Similar : [CORS policy conflict in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759527/cors-policy-conflict-in-spring-boot/56765503#56765503)